# Sorting algorithm for expensive comparison

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given is an array of `n` distinct objects (not integers), where `n` is between 5 and 15. I have a comparison function `cmp(a, b)` which is `true` if `a < b` and `false` otherwise, but it's very expensive to call. I'm looking for a sorting algorithm with the following properties:

- It calls `cmp(a, b)` as few times as possible (subject to constraints below). Calls to `cmp(a, b)` can't be parallelized or replaced. The cost is unavoidable, i.e. think of each call to `cmp(a, b)` as costing money.
- Aborting the algorithm should give good-enough results (best-fit sort of the array). Ideally the algorithm should attempt to produce a coarse order of the whole array, as opposed partially sorting one subset at a time. This may imply that the overall number of calls is not as small as theoretically possible to sort the entire array.
- `cmp(a, b)` implies `not cmp(b, a)` => No items in the array are equal => Stability is not required. This is always true, unless...
- In rare cases `cmp(a, b)` violates transitivity. For now I'll ignore this, but ultimately I would like this to be handled as well. Transitivity could be violated in short chains, i.e. x < y < z < x, but not in longer chains. In this case the final order of x y z doesn't matter.

Only the number of calls to `cmp()` needs to be optimized; algorithm complexity, space, speed and other factors are irrelevant.

#### Back story

Someone asked where this odd problem arose. Well, despite at my shallow attempt at formalism, the problem is actually not formal at all. A while back a friend of mine found a web page on the internets, that allowed him to put some stuff in a list, and make comparisons on that list in order to get it sorted. He since lost that web page, and asked me to help him out. Sure, I said and smashed my keyboard arriving at [this implemtation](http://dsort.azurewebsites.net). You are welcome to peruse the source code to see how i pretended to solve the problem above. Since I was quite inebriated when all this happened, I decided to outsource the real thinking to stack overflow.

Comment: Could there be a money-accuracy tradeoff with `cmp`? Can you get a likelihood score instead of true or false? There's nothing wrong with your model as is, but there's some relevant literature for related models.

Comment: In this model, assuming transitivity and ignoring the possibility of aborting, the best that you can do is an optimal decision tree for sorting, which should be known for small n, maybe not up to 15 because they probably are not concisely specifiable.

Comment: What the heck is "sorted" even supposed to mean with a non-transitive "order"? Do you just want adjacent elements to appear sorted in that case?

Comment: Actually, with the optimal decision tree, no redundant comparisons will be performed, so the possibilities after an abort happens will be the linear extensions of the observed comparisons, the number of which the optimal decision tree probably tends to minimize at each step. You may have a different idea of "good-enough" though.

Comment: What do you mean by '`n` distinct objects of size `n`'?

Comment: @user2357112, I have no formal definition how violation of transitivity could be handled. I could specify that if a << b << c, then a < c, where << is a length of a comparison chain. Then for a cycle x < y < z < x, we could sort x y z in any order.

Comment: `"Aborting the algorithm should give good-enough results"` - this is underspecified - how do you define the quality of results? You may need to specify whether this or minimum comparisons is more important, or give a weight to each.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, Interesting - there's no reasoning with cmp however, the cost is fixed, and we'd want to get a rough order as soon as possible, as opposed to totally sorted with as few comparisons as possible.

Comment: I tried solving something similar: Create a graph from the compares, do not show compares where a comparison was already done, and finally make a topological sorting

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to start with would be Chp 5 of Knuth's TAOCP Vol III..it is about optimal sorting (ie with minimal number of comparisons). OTOH, since the number of objects you are sorting is very small I doubt there will be any noticeable difference between an optimal algorithm vs, say, bubble sort. So perhaps you will need to focus on making the comparisons cheaper. Strange problem though...would you mind giving details? Where does it arise?

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. I've added a trivia section to my question showing in painful detail my thought process. ;)